# If another cells's first word = a cell, then change the cell to the last word

Tags: regex, google-sheets

Most weirdest question.. I understand.

Basically there is an events log, that says "Johno has changed his name to Johna" (example)

I want a script that will change the 'Johno' located in column A:A to Johna (based on the last word)

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take the [tour] and checkout [ask] to learn the ropes of this site.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [regular expression](https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax).

To match the first word, the syntax is `^\w*`, so `=regexextract("hello world","^\w*")` will give you "hello"

To match the last word, the syntax is either `\w*\z` or `\w*$`, so `=regexextract("hello world","\w*$")` will give you "world"

To replace last word with the first word, I tested the following

```
=regexreplace(
   "hello brave new world",
   "\w*$",
   regexextract("hello brave new world", "^\w*")
 )
```

Unfortunately it gives me "hello brave new hellohello". It looks like a bug (I tested similar code in Javascript and got "hello brave new hello" as expected).

So a workaround is something like

```
=REGEXREPLACE(A1 &".","(\w*[.])",REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"^\w*"))
```

which first adds "." to end of the string, and search for any word followed by "." instead.

Comment: well sometimes the names contain a space, so it could be Mohammud abir, is there any way to remove parts of the string in the text "has changed his name to" and grab the last data from there?

Comment: If the pattern is fixed, you can do something like =REGEXEXTRACT(A1,"(?:Hello\s?)(.*)") to extract everything after "Hello". The pattern Hello\s? means Hello followed by any space, and (?:) means don't capture the match, and .* means any character for any number of times.

Comment: Here is the link to an example

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XkmEOKIFsCZVBWpT21egaQGjECa6Qp9NMSW3kKj2RqE/edit#gid=1709847193

In column F there is a list of names, In column B the events log (auto updates) says when a person has changed their username, I want it to change the name for them on column F

So for example if 138K (in F3) changes his name and it shows up on the events log, i want the name in column F to change to what it says

Sometimes there are 2 or 3 spaces in each name but always follows with "Has changed their rsn to"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function onEdit(e)
{
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var editRange = sheet.getActiveRange();
  var editRow = editRange.getRow();
  var editCol = editRange.getColumn();
  var lr = sheet.getLastRow()
  var range = sheet.getRange("B:B");//only run when column B is changed
  var rangeRowStart = range.getRow();
  var rangeRowEnd = rangeRowStart + range.getHeight()-1;
  var rangeColStart = range.getColumn();
  var rangeColEnd = rangeColStart + range.getWidth()-1;
  if (editRow >= rangeRowStart && editRow <= rangeRowEnd 
      && editCol >= rangeColStart && editCol <= rangeColEnd)
  {
  var range = e.range;
  var val=e.range.getValue()//get sentence
  var name=val.split(" ").slice(-1)//get the last word
  var row = sheet.getActiveCell().getRowIndex();//get changed row number
  sheet.getRange(row,1 ).setValue(name);//set the name in column A
  }}
```